# sed insert variable before last line

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to insert a variable before the last line.

This is my file.

```
$ cat file.txt
one
two
three
four
five
```

When I try without using variables, it works fine.

```
$ sed -i '$i name' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
one
two
three
four
name
five
```

When I use a variable, it doesn't work. I tried different combinations of double quotes and backslashes.

```
$ NAME=name
$ sed -i '$i "$NAME"' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
one
two
three
four
"$NAME"
five
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, single-quotes are for fixed, literal strings.  Double quotes are used where you want variable interpolation, command substitution, etc to occur.

Your `sed` command needs to use both a literal `$` (so that the `i` command applies to the last line of the file) **AND** `$NAME` for the variable to interpolate.  To do this, you need to "escape" the literal `$` with a backslash so that the shell doesn't interpret the `$i` in your sed script as "replace with the contents of variable $i" instead of "literal `$` followed by literal `i`":

BTW, it's better to test things like this without using the `-i` option, so that `sed` doesn't mess up your input file while you're figuring out the correct syntax.  Add the `-i` later when you're sure it's doing exactly what you want.

```
$ NAME=name
$ sed "\$i $NAME" file.list 
one
two
three
four
name
five
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$ NAME=name
$ sed '$i '"$NAME" file.list
one
two
three
four
name
five
```